Raspberry Pi libcamera-vid to Youtube audio slows drifts out of sync
I am using the following command to stream directly to YouTube.  The problem is that over time the audio will slowly drift out of sync. I have looked at all the possible command line options and do not see a way to resync the audio periodically.  Any suggestions?
libcamera-vid --timeout 0 -g 10 --bitrate 3000000 --inline --verbose 0 --width 1920 --height 1080 --framerate 30  --codec libav --libav-format flv --libav-audio --audio-bitrate 128000 --av-sync 300000 -n 0 --preview 30,30,640,480 -o rtmp://a.rtmp.youtube.com/live2/$stream_key

